# Cassandra via PHP

Tags: php, cassandra

I have a client / server setup for Cassandra that works when accessed via Perl. Im trying to redo the process in PHP now. I can't seem to call any functions against my installation without getting a 'TSocket read 0 bytes' exception. Here is a sample that should be pretty straightforward:

```
$GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = '/usr/local/src/thrift-0.8.0/lib/php/src';

require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/packages/cassandra/Cassandra.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/packages/cassandra/cassandra_types.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/transport/TSocket.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/transport/TFramedTransport.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/transport/TBufferedTransport.php';

try {
 $socket = new TSocket( '10.127.24.19', 9160 );
 $transport = new TBufferedTransport( $socket, 1024, 1024 );
 $protocol = new TBinaryProtocolAccelerated( $transport );
 $client = new cassandra_CassandraClient( $protocol );
 $transport->open();

 $keyspace = 'some_data';

 $client->set_keyspace( $keyspace );

} 
catch (TException $tx)
{
   error_log( print_r( $tx, true ));
}
```

This is thrift 0.8.0, Cassandra 1.0, PHP 5.3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use raw thrift, use a library instead:

- https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa
- http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/

You will hit a never-ending list of gotcha's like this otherwise.