# Cassandra not working with php

Tags: php, nosql, cassandra

I am using cassandra with php. cassandra server and client. both have been started. It throws following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function write() on a non-object in C:\cassandra\thrift\Thrift.php on line 715

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  395808  {main}( )   ..\cassandra_testFile.php:0
2   0.0409  3143872 CassandraClient->insert( )  ..\cassandra_testFile.php:46
3   0.0409  3143872 CassandraClient->send_insert( ) ..\Cassandra.php:606
4   0.0412  3146072 cassandra_Cassandra_insert_args->write( )   ..\Cassandra.php:625
5   0.0412  3146136 TBase->_write( )    ..\Cassandra.php:2761
```

In call stack, at step 2. Line no. 46 is :

```
$client->insert($keyspace, $keyUserId, $columnPath, $value, $timestamp, $consistency_level);
```

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many, many, many people use a client in front of Thrift.  For PHP, the most common is [PHPCassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa)

- [Which PHP client library to use with Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401282/which-php-client-library-to-use-with-cassandra)
- [Cassandra via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858631/cassandra-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

Connection via Thrift deprecated.

[PHP library for Cassandra database via a binary protocol.](https://github.com/evseevnn/php-cassandra-binary)